# Widgets not displaying with macOS vibrancy (NSVisualEffectView)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, appkit, pyobjc

I have currently got a PyQt5 application which is quite simple (just one button). I'd like for it to have vibrancy, so I've ported ObjC vibrancy code to Python. My vibrancy code is as follows:

```
frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, * self.get_screen_size())  # get_screen_size returns the resolution of the monitor
view = objc.objc_object(c_void_p=self.winId().__int__())  # returns NSView of current window

visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView.new()
visualEffectView.setAutoresizingMask_(NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)  # equivalent to: visualEffectView.autoresizingMask = NSViewW...
visualEffectView.setFrame_(frame)
visualEffectView.setState_(NSVisualEffectStateActive)
visualEffectView.setMaterial_(NSVisualEffectMaterialDark)
visualEffectView.setBlendingMode_(NSVisualEffectBlendingModeBehindWindow)

window = view.window()
window.contentView().addSubview_positioned_relativeTo_(visualEffectView, NSWindowBelow, None)  
    # equal to: [window.contentView addSubview:visualEffectView positioned:NSWindowBelow relativeTo:nul]

window.setTitlebarAppearsTransparent_(True)
window.setStyleMask_(window.styleMask() | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask)  # so the title bar is also vibrant

self.repaint()
```

All I'm doing to draw a button is: `btn = QPushButton("test", self)`

`self` is a class inherited from `QMainWindow` and everything else should be fairly unimportant.

Behaviour with the `window.contentView().addSubview...` line commented out (no vibrancy)

[image]

Behaviour without it commented out (with vibrancy)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: I don't fully understand your question.  It kind of looks like you already have the desired affect ... or are those screenshots not your app?

Comment: @MaxvonHippel The window has the desired vibrancy effect. However, the "test" button which is visible in the first screenshot is not drawn in the second, when vibrancy is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The UI elements are actually drawn, but the `NSVisualEffectView` is covering them.
I fixed that issue by adding another view `QMacCocoaViewContainer` to the window.

You'll also need to set the Window transparent, otherwise the widgets will have a slight background border.

If you use the dark vibrant window also make sure to set appearance correctly, so buttons, labels etc. are rendered correctly.

```py
frame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height())
view = objc.objc_object(c_void_p=self.winId().__int__())

visualEffectView = NSVisualEffectView.new()
visualEffectView.setAutoresizingMask_(NSViewWidthSizable|NSViewHeightSizable)
visualEffectView.setWantsLayer_(True)
visualEffectView.setFrame_(frame)
visualEffectView.setState_(NSVisualEffectStateActive)
visualEffectView.setMaterial_(NSVisualEffectMaterialUltraDark)
visualEffectView.setBlendingMode_(NSVisualEffectBlendingModeBehindWindow)
visualEffectView.setWantsLayer_(True)

self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

window = view.window()
content = window.contentView()

container = QMacCocoaViewContainer(0, self)
content.addSubview_positioned_relativeTo_(visualEffectView, NSWindowBelow, container)  

window.setTitlebarAppearsTransparent_(True)
window.setStyleMask_(window.styleMask() | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask)

appearance = NSAppearance.appearanceNamed_('NSAppearanceNameVibrantDark')
window.setAppearance_(appearance)
```

Result:

[image]